# swaping variables in js

Tags: javascript, html

I want to 2 swap 2 variables by using javascript, here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function a(){

                var in1 = document.getElementById("i1").value;
                var in2 =  document.getElementById("i2").value;

                in1=in1+in2;
                in2=in1-in2;
                in1=in1-in2;

                document.getElementById("o1").value=in1;
                document.getElementById("o2").value=in2;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type=text id=i1><br>
        <input type=text id=i2><br>
        <input value=change type=button onclick="a();"><br>
        <input type=text id=o1><br>
        <input type=text id=o2>
    </body>
</html>
```

but when I run the function I got the values 1 & 10 instead of 1 & 2.

Comment: Just cast it to `Number()` : http://jsfiddle.net/fV2NQ/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use, *why complicate thing?*

```
var a = in1;
in1=in2;
in2=a;
```

***If you want to swap without using third variable***, cast them to `Number()`

```
in1 = Number(in1);
in2 = Number(in2);

in1=in1+in2;
```

Comment: OP is actually trying to swap without using third variable, I guess number conversion is the problem with his code.

Answer (score 1):

Why to swap if you are assigning values to other ids.

```
  document.getElementById("o1").value=document.getElementById("i2").value;
  document.getElementById("o2").value=document.getElementById("i1").value;
```

Comment: surely this way is better, but I want too to use that swapping way for education purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse them to number like this:

```
in1 = parseInt(in1);
in2 = parseInt(in2);
```

[test here](http://jsfiddle.net/2yUJD/)

Answer (score 1):

The values in both the variables are of *string* type rather than *Integers*. To perform numeric operations we need to first convert string values into Integers ::

`var in1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("i1").value);

var in2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("i2").value);`

Just replace your code with the above one and it will work fine!!